Understanding lifetimes within options in rust
I have the following code:
LiveDemo
struct State<'w> {
    surface: &'w u32,
}

impl<'w> State<'w> {
    fn new(window: &'w u32) -> State {
        State {
            surface: window
        }
    }
}

#[derive(Default)]
struct App<'w> {
    state: Option<State<'w>>,
    window: Option<u32>,
}

impl<'w> App<'w> {
    fn resume(&mut self) {
        self.window = Some(1);
        let state = State::new(&self.window.as_ref().unwrap());
        self.set_state(state);
    }

    fn set_state(&mut self, state: State<'w>) {
        self.state = Some(state);
    }
}

fn main()
{
    let mut app = App::default();
    app.resume();
}

Now I know this is a self referential struct. But before I try to fix it I first want to wrap my head around what it actually means for a lifetime to be attached to an option of a reference?
AI tells me something like this:

The error you're encountering is due to the fact that the lifetime 'w
of the App<'w> struct is not properly aligned with the lifetimes of
the references within the State<'w> struct.

But this makes it sound like <'w> denotes the lifetime of the whole App struct, is that true? I initially thought that <'w> is just a generic parameter that tells the compiler that "lifetimes are involved", since in my book the lifetime 'w starts only when the state object is instantiated (in the call to set_state) since the Option previously defaults to None. That point could be long after the lifetime of App has begun (in main()). Am I incorrect in assuming so? Maybe someone could shed some light on this, it's a very confusing topic for me as a beginner :)
Edit: These are the errors:
error: lifetime may not live long enough
  --> <source>:23:9
   |
19 | impl<'w> App<'w> {
   |      -- lifetime `'w` defined here
20 |     fn resume(&mut self) {
   |               - let's call the lifetime of this reference `'1`
...
23 |         self.set_state(state);
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ argument requires that `'1` must outlive `'w`

error[E0502]: cannot borrow `*self` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable
  --> <source>:23:9
   |
19 | impl<'w> App<'w> {
   |      -- lifetime `'w` defined here
...
22 |         let state = State::new(&self.window.as_ref().unwrap());
   |                                 ----------- immutable borrow occurs here
23 |         self.set_state(state);
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |         |
   |         mutable borrow occurs here
   |         argument requires that `self.window` is borrowed for `'w`


As a side note, it's generally helpful if you include the error message in your question.

@Green绿色 True, edited :)

The error message you're probably getting is this:
error: lifetime may not live long enough
  --> <source>:23:9
   |
19 | impl<'w> App<'w> {
   |      -- lifetime `'w` defined here
20 |     fn resume(&mut self) {
   |               - let's call the lifetime of this reference `'1`
...
23 |         self.set_state(state);
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ argument requires that `'1` must outlive `'w`

As this error message clearly states, it refers to the lifetime '1 of the &mut self reference not being as long as 'w. So, it doesn't has to do anything with our Option object. For the compiler, &self is just a reference, it apparently has no innate connection to the lifetime of the App class, so when you make this explicit, the error will go away:
fn resume(&'w mut self) {
    self.window = Some(1);
    let state = State::new(&self.window.as_ref().unwrap());
    self.set_state(state);
}

Warning ⚠️: this code compiles, but it renders self unusable after it's first use. &'w mut self creates a mutable borrow of self with the lifetime of 'w, which is also the lifetime of App. As a consequence, we cannot create any more references to self. For more details, see @Cerberus' answer.
However, the compiler will greet you with another error:
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `*self` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable
  --> <source>:23:9
   |
19 | impl<'w> App<'w> {
   |      -- lifetime `'w` defined here
...
22 |         let state = State::new(&self.window.as_ref().unwrap());
   |                                 --------------------
   |                                 |
   |                                 immutable borrow occurs here
   |                                 argument requires that `self.window` is borrowed for `'w`
23 |         self.set_state(state);
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ mutable borrow occurs here

error: aborting due to 1 previous error

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0502`.
ASM generation compiler returned: 1

This is because you cannot have both, an immutable and a mutable reference, to the same object, in this case self. This way, the compiler protects you from race conditions. As stated in the error message, the immutable reference is created when you create the state variable, and the mutable reference when you call set_state. Since the lifetime of state overlaps with the call to set_state, this error is reported. One possibility to make this work is to get rid of the set_state method:
fn resume(&'w mut self) {
    self.window = Some(1);
    let state = State::new(&self.window.as_ref().unwrap());
    self.state = Some(state);
}

It's often helpful to have a closer look at the error messages of the Rust compiler. They often provide helpful clues to where and why the code doesn't compile. As a beginner in Rust myself, I know they can be cryptic at times, but the more you interpret, the clearer they become.
As a side note, the new constructor of the State struct is redundant in this example, you could just use the default constructor as follows:
let state = State {
    surface: &self.window.as_ref().unwrap(),
}

As I understand it, the new constructor is only useful if your parameters differ from the actual members of the struct, e.g., if you want to, for example, instantiate your State with one or multiple objects of a different kind.

Note also that &'something mut self with Foo<'something> is almost always a bad idea, since it effectively renders Foo forever unusable in any way other than this reference - see https://quinedot.github.io/rust-learning/pf-self.html for some more info.

Thx for the answer, but I still have questions:

Does 'w denote the lifetime of the App class or the one of the optional reference?
Is this phrasing correct: The first error states that the compiler doesn't know if the lifetime of the app-borrow (&mut self) will outlive the window-borrow stuffed into the option, which is necessary for the set_state function?
I would have thought that the borrow of &self.window.as_ref() would be dropped right after the call to State::new(), so that `self.set_state(state) doesn't cross the immutable borrow. Why isn't this the case?


"I would have thought that the borrow of &self.window.as_ref() would be dropped right after the call to State::new()" This is a very good question to which I'd like to know the answer as well.

"Does 'w denote the lifetime of the App class or the one of the optional reference?" As far as I understand it, 'w denotes the lifetime of the App object as well as the State object, and by extension it's containing reference. By assigning 'w to both of them, you effectively specify that the App object must live as long as the reference. The Option is the owner of State, so the State object's lifetime is naturally tied to this Option's lifetime.

@Cerberus Thanks for the hint. Is there a better solution to this specific problem? Or is there more information, because the document you linked to is very barebone.

@Green绿色 But won't I have to annotate App<'w> if any of the fields within the struct use this lifetime? I can't just leave <'w> away for App<'w> right? So naturally this generics will always propagate up the struct-hierarchy I guess? :/

@glades The compiler needs some guarantee on how long the reference in State  lives to make sure that the referred object doesn't disappear before the reference is still alive. You need to anchor this object's lifetime somewhere. Because it refers to App's window member, which lives as long as App is living, you have to anchor it to App. I don't know if there's a way to directly link it to window's lifetime.

The main fundamental problem of your code is that you're trying to build a self-referential struct (self.state points into self.window), which are notoriously hard to do properly in Rust and almost unusable if one restricts oneself to safe code only.

In general, references are expected to point on something external - that is, on something that's stored out of the current struct; they are something like temporary views somewhere else. But here you're trying to have a struct which is "a temporary view into itself", which is, semantically, a contradiction:

On the one hand, struct must outlive any view into itself, since otherwise these views will dangle.
On the other hand, view must not outlive the struct it's referring to - for the same reason.

Combined, these two things lead to the fact that the view and the struct itself must cease to exist at exact same time - but this is impossible in general, since fields of any struct are dropped in some sequential order, not simultaneously. In practice, this exact restiction can be avoided, but semantically that's the gist of the problem.
Note also that we don't speak here at all about the time when reference is created. It is, essentially, not important here: we're guaranteed that at the moment of creation any reference is valid (unless there's some unsound code, of course); the question is whether it stays valid until destruction.

The &'a mut Struct<'a> antipattern is usually a sign of some self-referentiality, too, and in fact it presents exactly the same problem as described above:

&'a mut Something means that 'a must be no longer than the scope of Something, since otherwise this reference would dangle when this scope ends.
Something<'a> means that 'a must be no shorter than the scope of Something, since otherwise some reference inside Something would dangle when this lifetime ends.

Combined, we have the struct that's "borrowed forever" and therefore unusable, except through reborrows of this reference (in partucular, it cannot have any impl Drop, since this counts as a use).

How, then, to fix the problem?
Judging by the provided code only, you actually can have not two, but three possible categories of states:

It can be unset (probably when the app is paused) - now it's modeled by None.
It can be set to some external value, i.e. if you pass some State from the surrounding scope into set_state.
It can be set as "pointing to self.window, as when you've just called App::resume.

What I would suggest to do here is to explicitly split these three cases, by storing a custom enum instead of Option<State>:
enum State<'w> {
    Unset,
    SelfWindow,
    External { surface: &'w u32 },
}

impl<'w> Default for State<'w> {
    fn default() -> Self {
        Self::Unset
    }
}

impl<'w> State<'w> {
    fn new(window: &'w u32) -> State<'w> {
        State::External { surface: window }
    }
}

Playground
Without seeing the full code, I can't be sure whether this approach will work in your actual case though.

Thanks for the explanation of the &'a mut self anti-pattern. I'll edit my answer to warn about it. So, there's no sane way to make it work without refactoring the surrounding code, specifically State, right?

Either State or App likely should be changed, yes.
